# Updating GridView row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview that changes a cell value to dateTime whenever I click the review button. Now, my problem is whenever I want to update that particular row, the whole column updates to dateTime. Is there something wrong with the update sql statement which might be causing this problem? Please help. Thanks!

```
protected void GridViewReview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Review"))
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        Label label = row.FindControl("lbl_reviewDate") as Label;
        label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnectionstringPIM"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string queryString = @"
                UPDATE [dbo].[Group]
                SET [lastreview] = @lastreview
                FROM [PIM].[dbo].[Group] AS g
                  INNER JOIN [Department] AS d
                  ON g.departmentID = d.id
                  INNER JOIN [HOD] AS h
                  ON d.hodid = h.id  
                 WHERE h.uid = h.uid";

            SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastreview", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = label.Text;

            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your SQL Statement updates the table based on your inner join condition. if you want it for that row only then give it the record ID to limit it down to that row.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas can you pls give me an example

Answer (score 3):

An `UPDATE` statement updates all rows in the table, unless a `WHERE` clause us used, in which case only the matching rows are updated. In your case, `WHERE h.uid = h.uid` is always going to be true (might as well read 1 = 1) hence it updates all rows, because all rows match the clause. Looks like a typo to me. I assume you actually want to compare h.uid to another identifier, not to itself.

Comment: what do you mean it updates all rows? i only want to update a single row

Comment: @alicewannabe I have updated the answer with a little more explanation.

Comment: oh i understand. in this case, what should i do in order to update only that specific row that i've selected?